# Control fields not working in CKEditor contained within jQuery UI modal dialog

Tags: jquery, recursion, modal-dialog, ckeditor

This is something that people have had problems with for a long time, but it is still an issue. When CKEditor is used within a jQuery UI modal dialog, the control fields of the editor cannot be accessed. For example, if you try to add a link, you are unable to type in the URL field.

Looking at previous solutions that have been suggested, the code that worked for me was as follows:

```
orig_allowInteraction = $.ui.dialog.prototype._allowInteraction;
$.ui.dialog.prototype._allowInteraction = function(event){
    // address interaction issues with general iframes with the dialog
    if (event.target.ownerDocument != this.document[0]){
        return true;
    }
    // address interaction issues with dialog window
    if ($(event.target).closest(".cke_dialog").length){
        return true;
    }
    // address interaction issues with iframe based drop downs in IE
    if ($(event.target).closest(".cke").length){
        return true;
    }
    return orig_allowInteraction.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

However, this code is not perfect because I have the following problems:

1. Firefox (v.36.0.4) – mostly working, but I am getting a lot of "**Too much recursion**" errors.
2. In Internet Explorer (v.11) I get "**Out of stack space**" errors. It mostly still works.
3. In Chrome and Opera, when the form is opened modally, the datepicker does not close after selecting a date for a date field. It just stays open.

Any idea how to solve these issues? I am using the latest versions at the time of writing as follows:

- CKEditor v.4.4.7
- jQuery v.1.11.2
- jQuery v.1.11.4

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code, don't know how it works, but it saves me 2 hours

```
$.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = function () {
    var $modalElement = this.$element;
    $(document).on('focusin.modal', function (e) {
        var $parent = $(e.target.parentNode);
        if ($modalElement[0] !== e.target && !$modalElement.has(e.target).length
            // add whatever conditions you need here:
            &&
            !$parent.hasClass('cke_dialog_ui_input_select') && !$parent.hasClass('cke_dialog_ui_input_text')) {
            $modalElement.focus()
        }
    })
};
```